# EnsureDeletedAsync broken after upgrade, .NET 3.1 to .NET 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mstest

I'm working on a .NET Core application in Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10. I'm using Entity Framework Core and, for unit testing, MSTest. I have the following code in my unit test project to initialize the database context and to clear the database between tests:

```
public static MyDbContext DbContext;

...

public async static Task InitializeDatabase()
{
    ConfigureDbContext();
    try
    {
        await DbContext.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
    } catch(Exception e) // I just added this so I'd have a place to put a breakpoint for debugging
    {
        throw;
    }
}

private static void ConfigureDbContext()
{
    MemoryCacheOptions memoryCacheOptions = new MemoryCacheOptions
    {
        SizeLimit = 10000000
    };
    IMemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
    DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase("DataInMemory")
        .Options;
    DbContext = new MyDbContext(options);
}
```

This worked fine under .NET Core 3.1. I migrated to .NET Core 6, including a move to the latest version of the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore packages. Now the call to `DbContext.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync()` throws the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'There are multiple [ForeignKey] attributes which are pointing to same set of properties '{'ParentId'}' on entity type 'BusinessLine' and targeting the principal entity type 'BusinessLine'.'

I'm confused by this in two ways. First, if the foreign keys are a barrier to the application figuring out how to accomplish this, why weren't they a barrier under .NET 3.1?

Second, according to [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.ensuredeletedasync?view=efcore-6.0), what `EnsureDeletedAsync` does is delete the database outright. Here, my confusion further branches in two directions. (a) If the database is being deleted outright, then what do the foreign key relationships among the tables within a database have to do with deleting the database altogether? (b) I see now that what's prescribed is for EnsureDeletedAsync to be followed by EnsureCreatedAsync. My code lacks the latter, yet, somehow, before the migration, my code worked.

So, does EnsureDeletedAsync delete data from tables while leaving the tables, as well as the database, in existence. Or does it wipe out the entire database? Can somebody help sort this out for me, and point me in the direction of a once-again working unit test project?

***Update:*** The code for BusinessLine is here:

```
    public class BusinessLine
    {
        public int BusinessLineId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DataDescriptor")]
        public int DataDescriptorId { get; set; }

        public int Level { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Parent")]
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AssetClass")]
        public int? AssetClassId { get; set; }

        public string BusinessLineName { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime UpdateDateTime { get; set; }

        // Foreign key relationships
        public BusinessLine Parent { get; set; }

        public AssetClass AssetClass { get; set; }

        public DataDescriptor DataDescriptor { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
        public List<BusinessLine> Sublines { get; set; }

    }
}
```

It has a foreign key relationship to itself because it's hierarchical.

The stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ForeignKeyAttributeConvention.UpdateRelationshipBuilder(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder, IConventionContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ForeignKeyAttributeConvention.ProcessForeignKeyAdded(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnForeignKeyAdded(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnForeignKeyAddedNode.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.DelayedConventionScope.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelInitialized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelInitialized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model..ctor(ConventionSet conventions, ModelDependencies modelDependencies, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder..ctor(ConventionSet conventions, ModelDependencies modelDependencies, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelConfigurationBuilder.CreateModelBuilder(ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.get_Dependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureDeletedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at [...].UnitTests.Overhead.Common.<InitializeDatabase>d__12.MoveNext() in [...].UnitTests\Overhead\Common.cs:line 195
```

Comment: The error complains about the class `BusinessLine`, not `EnsureDeletedAsync`. You didn't post the class so it's impossible to guess how to fix the problem. The error says there are multiple `ForeignKey` attributes pointing to the same Parent. Post the relevant code - the `BusinessLine` class and the `DbContext.OnModelConfiguring` method

Comment: Without the relevant code the question should be closed because it lacks relevant information. As for why EF Core 3.1 didn't crash, it's because it didn't detect the conflicting attributes. I suspect you tried to create multiple relations to the same type by using `ForeignKey` attributes instead of conventions or specifying relations in the DbContext.

Comment: I think the specifics of BusinessLine are irrelevant. It's simply pointing out that there are tables with foreign keys--which, of course, can hamper an attempt to delete data from a table if other tables have related rows. As for EF Core 3.1 not "detecting" conflicting attributes, the point is that it successfully did what I expected it to do. So it's more like .NET 6 is *imagining* there to be a conflict where none exists.

Comment: Again: If EnsureDeletedAsync is deleting the database outright, as the documentation claims, then the foreign key relationships among the tables should be irrelevant, correct?

Comment: Yes, but the problem isn't about that method at all. The specifics of `BusinessLine` are the only relevant part. The error complains about that class, not deleting. Even if EF Core 6 is somehow broken, it's *that* class where the problem appears

Comment: It complains about it nowhere until the moment that I happen to be calling EnsureDeletedAsync. It doesn't complain when I create the database. It doesn't complain when I populate it. So how do you figure that that call, the call where the exception is thrown, has nothing to do with it? As far as you know, BusinessLine just happens to be the first table it looks at when trying to execute the call; if it looked at another table first, then it would mention *that* table.

Comment: At which moment the DbContext is created, the `OnModelConfiguring` method is called, the metadata is calculated and the problem is thrown. If you simply tried to use the DbContext you'd get the same error. If you posted the actual full exception text, including the stack trace you'd see where the exception is *actually* thrown and what calls were involved.

Comment: BTW `public static MyDbContext DbContext;` is a major bug. A DbContext isn't a connection or database model, it's a Unit-of-Work, meant to be created right before it's used and disposed immediately afterwards. The DbContext tracks all changes made to objects in memory and only persists (in a single transaction) them if `SaveChanges` is called. A static instance means that the changes will be tracked indefinitely with no way to discard them

Comment: I've added the code for BusinessLine and the stack trace.

Comment: As the stack trace shows, the error is thrown when constructing the model. The error is justified too, as the two `ForeignKey` attributes result in a circular reference. That class says `the FK column for the 1:M Sublines relation is ParentID. No wait, that's the FK for the Parent 'M:1' relation`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244472/discussion-between-green-grasso-holm-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Oh dear. I can't continue in chat because the chat URL is evidently blocked by my organization's network. Anyway, as I indicated to Blindy below, I don't understand how, without it being specified, the framework would know the Sublines is specifically the name of a collection that is formed specifically based on a column called ParentId, *but* I tried removing that attribute, and it worked. So, thank you for your patience, and for the details.

Comment: I don't disagree about my use of DbContext. I was new to Core at the time, and came to grips with how DI works only through the course of my work. I found handling it with DbContext particularly frustrating. Anyway, if I were starting from scratch, I'd do it correctly. For now, it works. (This isn't a multiuser application, fortunately. It's a batch process.)

Answer (score 1):

```
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public List<BusinessLine> Sublines { get; set; }
```

That's not how the foreign key attribute is supposed to be called. Simply delete it and it will fix this problem.

In fact, you don't need any foreign key attributes at all, you're polluting your class for no reason. The id + object reference pattern is enough to build the table structure.

Comment: Without being told, how would it know that a column called "ParentId" is what maps Sublines to their parent line?

Comment: EF.Core is a convention-based ORM. You simply read the documentation.

Comment: I've read the documentation. It tells me the framework understands that MyTable has a primary key column called Id or MyTableId, etc. But I haven't seen any suggestion in it that one of the conventions is for the word "Sublines" to be interpreted to refer to all rows from the same table called BusinessLines whose ParentId column matches the current row's Id value.

Comment: While my previous comment stands, insofar as I don't understand *why* it would work, I did understand that I was in some manner double-specifying the relationship, and removed the ForeignKey attribute as you indicated. And it worked. So thank you for that.

Comment: "one of the conventions is for the word "Sublines" to be interpreted" it's not that random word that's not even English that's interpreted, it's the property *type* that is. You declared it as a `List<T>` (it should actually be `DbSet<>`), where `T` is of a DB entity type, which triggers the one-to-many mapping mechanism.

Comment: Also, if you're familiar with relational databases at all, you should know that the foreign key isn't part of the `BusinessLine` table, it's part of a second table that maps business lines to other lines and is of the form (`id`, `business_line_id`, `sub_business_line_id`). The two fields there are both foreign keys into `BussinessLine`.

Comment: There is no second table. As I said, it's a hierarchical table.

Microsoft's own documentation uses List. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Declaring the property as List<T> doesn't tell it *which* numeric column keys into the table associated with type T.

Comment: DbSet is used to declare the entities in the DbContext class, not the many-to-one properties in the individual model classes.